# 16 x 2 LCD not displaying analog inputs fed to ATmega168

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, lcd

I am experiencing some problems getting a display of analog inputs(current and voltage) fed to ATmega168's A0 and A1 respectively. I believe the wiring and the program are correct since the same circuit works perfectly well on Proteus simulation.
I have even tried to display "Hello World" contained in the IDE examples but there was no display.Iam using Arduino Diecimila or Duemilanove w/ATmega168 programming kit with micro controller connected externally to a breadboard.

Here is my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
int relayPin =7;
int buzzerPin=6;               
intled2Pin=8;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);  
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led1Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2Pin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  float sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0)*28.35;
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(voltage);
  lcd.print("V,");
  float sensorValue1 = analogRead(A1);
  float current = sensorValue1 * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
  lcd.print(current);
  lcd.print("A,");
  float Power = (voltage * current)/1000; 
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(Power);
  lcd.print("kW");

  if ((current >=3.0 && current <=4.0) && (voltage >=90 && voltage <=120)){

    digitalWrite (led1Pin,HIGH); // blink green led

  } else {

    digitalWrite (led2Pin,HIGH);//blink red led
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite (led2Pin,LOW);
    delay(300);

  }
  if(current >4.0 && current<4.3) {

    digitalWrite (led2Pin,HIGH); // blink red led
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite (led2Pin,LOW);
    delay(300);

  }
  if(voltage >120 && voltage<130) {

    digitalWrite (led2Pin,HIGH);//blink red led
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite (led2Pin,LOW);
    delay(300);

  }

  if(current >=4.3) {

    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite (relayPin,HIGH); // activate relay for trip
    digitalWrite(buzzerPin,HIGH); // sound buzzer or alarm

  }
  if(voltage >= 130) {

    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite (relayPin,HIGH);//activate relay for trip
    digitalWrite(buzzerPin,HIGH);//sound buzzer or alarm

  }


}
```

Comment: Samson, you would get better responses if you could distill the code down to the barest minimum which should deliver the specific minimal functionality that is not working. For that, you would have to understand the code, and knock off the parts not directly relevant.

Comment: If the example 'hello world' does not work that makes it sound more like a wiring/connection issue and not a code issue, can you post some details/schematic of the hardware?

Comment: Please add a picture of your setup. And as @AnindoGhosh mentions, please remove unimportant parts of the source code. More than once this step had me find my problem by myself.